# Style guide/typeface for handwritten mathematics

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing

When writing math on graph paper, it's a small struggle to make my work as legible as possible and also use the page as efficiently as possible.

I've read a little online about how latex typesets, and also a little on how typesetting mathematics worked before latex. These systems are pretty complex.

What system do you personally use to make your work as legible as possible?

For example, do you put extra space around your arithmetic operators? A newline between every line? Do you write your quotients all on one line rather than draw a numerator above a denominator? Color changes?

Do style guides exist specifically for *handwritten* mathematics?